# FileNotFoudException occur when zipping file because of output zip file open failed ENOTDIR

Tags: java, android

I am newbie in android.i am currently developing  mulitple files zip in my project
i have a create Array list and use it as source files but i have got filenotfoundexception  in pinstacktrace  that says Testzip which is my outputfile open failed ENOTDIR. I dont know why is happening . i have tried to convert Arraylist in String Array but nothing happend but garbage value created how could i solve this problem. The Zipfile(ArrayListzipinputlist)is my zipfunction

Here is my code

```
package com.example.testmutilplefile;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static String TAG = "SelectFiles";
    // public static String ZIP="zippingfile";
    public File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    public ListView directorytree;
    public ListView filetree;
    public TextView directorynames;
    public TextView files;
    public Button sdclick;
    public ArrayList<File> resultFilelist;
    public ArrayList<File> directorylist = new ArrayList<File>();
    public ArrayList<String> directoryname = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<File> filelist = new ArrayList<File>();
    public ArrayList<String> myfilename = new ArrayList<String>();
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    FileInputStream fileinput;
    FileOutputStream fileoutput;
    ZipOutputStream zipout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initialComponent();
        sdclick.setClickable(true);

    }

    public void initialComponent() {

        sdclick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sdcardbutton);
        directorynames = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.directoriesname);
        files = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.filesname);
        directorytree = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.directorySelectionList);
        filetree = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.fileSelectionList);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_select_file, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onTestClick(MenuItem item) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Testclicked, Activity Finishing");
        resultFilelist = new ArrayList<File>();

        for (int i = 0; i < filetree.getCount(); i++) {
            if (filetree.isItemChecked(i)) {
                System.out.println(" Selected File is"
                        + resultFilelist.add(filelist.get(i)));

                Toast.makeText(this, "selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }

        if (resultFilelist.isEmpty()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "NO File ADDED");
            finish();
        }

        // String fileArray= resultFilelist;

        System.out.println(resultFilelist);

        Log.d(TAG, "Files:" + resultFilelist);
        ArrayList<File> zipInputList = resultFilelist;
        zipFile(zipInputList);

        // File []zipinputArray= resultFilelist.toArray(new
        // File[resultFilelist.size()]);
        // Log.d(TAG,"FileArray"+ zipinputArray.toString());

    }

    private void zipFile(ArrayList<File> zipInputList) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(TAG, "Current Input files are:" + zipInputList);

        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        String zippedfile = path + File.separator + "Test.zip";
        try {
            fileoutput = new FileOutputStream(zippedfile);
            zipout = new ZipOutputStream(fileoutput);
            for (int i = 0; i < zipInputList.size(); i++) {

                File storagefileindex = new File(zipInputList.get(i),
                        zippedfile);
                Log.v(TAG, "Add:" + zipInputList.get(i));
                Log.v("compressing", "Adding" + zipInputList.get(i));
                fileinput = new FileInputStream(storagefileindex);
                zipout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(storagefileindex.getName()));
                int bytecount;

                while ((bytecount = fileinput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    zipout.write(buffer, 0, bytecount);
                }
                zipout.closeEntry();
                 fileinput.close();

            }
            zipout.close();


        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(zippedfile, "Error occurs in Creating zip");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void onSdCardListener(View v) {
        File parentfile = filepath.getParentFile();
        Log.d(TAG, parentfile.toString());
        listTree();

        /*
         * if (filepath.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())) {
         * Toast.makeText(this, "cant exit external storage",
         * Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); listTree();
         * 
         * }
         *//*
             * else { filepath = parentfile; //listTree();
             * 
             * }
             */
    }

    private void listTree() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FileFilter filefilter = new FileFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File file) {
                return file.isFile();

            }

        };
        FileFilter directoryfilter = new FileFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File file) {
                return file.isDirectory();
            }
        };
        /* List of Directory */
        if (filepath.exists() && filepath.length() > 0) {
            File[] directorylistArray = filepath.listFiles(directoryfilter);
            for (File file : directorylistArray) {
                directorylist.add(file);
                directoryname.add(file.getName());
            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> directoryadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, directoryname);
            directorytree.setAdapter(directoryadapter);
            File[] filelistArray = filepath.listFiles(filefilter);

            for (File file : filelistArray) {
                filelist.add(file);
                myfilename.add(file.getName());

            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> fileadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myfilename);
            filetree.setAdapter(fileadapter);
            Log.d(TAG, "List Created");

        }

    }

}
```

and my exception output is

```
01-17 14:01:02.322: V/compressing(854): Adding/storage/sdcard/formpicture.JPG
01-17 14:01:02.332: D//storage/sdcard/Test.zip(854): Error occurs in Creating zip
01-17 14:01:02.332: W/System.err(854): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard/formpicture.JPG/storage/sdcard/Test.zip: open failed: ENOTDIR (Not a directory)
01-17 14:01:02.352: W/System.err(854):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
01-17 14:01:02.352: W/System.err(854):  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to acces to : /storage/sdcard/formpicture.JPG/storage/sdcard/Test.zip in the line `File storagefileindex = new File(zipInputList.get(i), zippedfile);` in zipFile function.

Use just `File storagefileindex = new File(zipInputList.get(i));`

Comment: Thanks for your reply but  i did it before . eclipse is showing  the constructor File(file ) is undefined

Comment: thanks  for your direction, i just  changed it into
File  storagefileindex=zipInputList.get(i); and it works  :)